# Yaml Object Lists

Tags: c#, serialization, yaml

I want to deserialize a list of objects with yaml.dotnet

You can see my YAML and source code below.

I get the Error that lesson is not part of my lesson object. So for any reason the compiler is expecting that "`Lesson`" is a property on the class

**Code:**

```
var deserializer = new Deserializer();
var items = deserializer.Deserialize<List<YamlLesson>>(yaml);
```

**YAML:**

```
Lessons:
  - ShortKey: "M/A/L"
    Type: Static
    Items: ["M","A","M","L"]
  - ShortKey: "der/die/datas"
    Type: "random"
    Items: ["der","die","das"]
```

**Class to which the yaml should be mapped**

```
 public sealed class YamlLesson
    {
        public string ShortKey { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Exception**:

> YamlDotNet.Core.YamlException: '(Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0) - (Line: 1,
>   Col: 1, Idx: 0): Expected 'SequenceStart', got 'MappingStart' (at
>   Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0).'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is that you tell YamlDotNet that you want to deserialize into a `List<YamlLesson>`, so YamlDotNet expects the root element of your YAML to be a *sequence*. However, your YAML's root element is a *mapping*: It has one key, `Lessons`, and the corresponding value, a sequence of lessons.

This YAML could be properly deserialized into this class:

```
public class Root {
  public List<YamlLesson> Lessons { get; set; };
}
```

However, if you want to deserialize directly to the List, just drop the root mapping and change your YAML to be

```
- ShortKey: "M/A/L"
  Type: Static
  Items: ["M","A","M","L"]
- ShortKey: "der/die/datas"
  Type: "random"
  Items: ["der","die","das"]
```