# Parsing a simple YAML file in C#

Tags: c#, yaml

I have the `YAML` file shown below.

```
Main: 
  GPort: 1234
  IPort: 3000
  Prefix: "192.168.0"
```

I have written the following function to parse the file.

```
        public static ProgramConfiguration LoadConfiguration(string config)
        {
            var deserializer = new Deserializer();
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(config);
            var result = deserializer.Deserialize<ProgramConfiguration>(sr);
            ProgramConfiguration bc = new ProgramConfiguration();

            return result;
        }
```

where

```
public class ProgramConfiguration 
{
    public string Prefix { get; set;}
    public int GPort { get; set; }
    public int IPort { get; set; }
}
```

The function LoadConfiguration throws an error.

`An unhandled exception of type 'YamlDotNet.Core.YamlException' occurred in YamlDotNet.dll`

at

`var result = deserializer.Deserialize<ProgramConfiguration>(sr);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to use "NetworkPrefix" in the class, but you have "Prefix" in the YAML file?

Comment: You're missing the `Main` element - you should try to deserialize to `class Config { public ProgramConfiguration Main { get; set; } }`

Comment: pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966647/yaml-object-lists), people tend to forget to deserialize the root element (in this case, a mapping containing the key `Main` and a mapping as value which maps to the `ProgramConfiguration` class.